# IOS7 UIWebView does not rotate

Tags: uiwebview, ios7

I have simple UIWebView app that load the html, the problem is that the UIWebView does not rotate when I rotate the device.

Here is the ViewController.m

```
#import "WrapperViewController.h"

@implementation WrapperViewController

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    NSBundle *bundle   = [NSBundle mainBundle]; 
    NSString *path     = [bundle bundlePath];
    NSString *fullPath = [NSBundle pathForResource:@"index"
                         ofType:@"htm" inDirectory:path];

    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                         [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullPath]]];

}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}


- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:
  (UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
   webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
   webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

}

- (void) didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: is your WrapperViewController presented modally?

Comment: Not sure, I am very new to iOS, how can I find that out or correct it, pls help

Comment: how are you presenting it? are you calling `presentViewController:` or pushing it in a navigation controller?

Comment: No not calling presentViewController, but not sure to confirm if pushing it in navigation, how to find that out?

Comment: how does your view controller appear? is it the first controller that opens? how are you setting it up? in a xib or storyboard file?

Comment: in the xib file WrapperViewController.xib. I have put UIViewControl in it as full screen